# sp_BlitzIndex finding "Unknown" index

Tags: index, sp-blitzindex

I am going through cleaning up one of our databases, and after deleting an unused index and adding a primary key to the `ARPayments` table, `sp_BlitzIndex` is now reporting an index `dbo.ARPayment.Unknown (0)`. I have refreshed my indexes and there is definitely no sign of any such index.

Here is the message it shows in the output from running `sp_BlitzIndex 'db_name', @Mode=4`:

> Should this table be a heap? dbo.ARPayment.Unknown (0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sp_BlitzIndex will list Unknown for the index name when the table is a heap. It's not saying you have an index named Unknown. The primary key that you added was added as non-clustered, and you don't have a clustered index on the table. A heap is a table without a clustered index.

If you don't want your table to be a heap, you could drop the PK and recreate it as a clustered PK.